# What is the purpose of using .getChildren().addAll() in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

Sample code:

> ```
>    HBox pane = new HBox(10); //new HBox pane
>    pane.getChildren().addAll(lbl, btnAdd, btnSubtract);
> ```

I know how to implement and get this code to do what I want, but I'm not sure what each piece does. It would make more sense if I did not have to specify the lbl,btnadd,btnsubtract objects. If it executes addAll why do I have to specify all the buttons I already have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your button is already in the list of children that the `HBox` has, then you should not add it in. On the other hand, if your `HBox` does not have that child (e.g. Button `btnAdd`), then it wouldn't appear at all if you don't add it in.

If you are imagining that the `HBox` would magically make `lbl`, `btnAdd` and `btnSubtract` into its children because you have simply created those objects with codes, then you are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX is centered on the idea of a Tree. HBox represent a node in that tree. If you use addAll() you are saying that HBox pane is not anymore a "leaf" (a node without children) and has inherited some children. That's also the concept of the JavaFX Parent class.